# Is there a "request sent - waiting for response event" when dynamically loading an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

When dynamically inserting an iframe into a webpage, the JQuery load event allows me to trigger a callback function when this iframe is loaded (see also [this stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205087/jquery-ready-in-a-dynamically-inserted-iframe)).

The problem I am struggling with, is that I want to do something when the src request is sent to the server but *before* the response is received from that server. In other words, I am looking for an event like "request fired". The JQuery load event doesn't seem to help here.

I have been playing with several values for the JQuery setTimeout method, but that doesn't look like a very robust solution to me.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you would need that event. When you call the JQuery method, you know the request is being made so you would call your method there.

Comment: I agree.  @Matthijs, can you explain why you are looking for a little more clearly.  It sounds like the request would be sent immediately when you insert the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

The iframe loads the "src" url as soon as its added to the document.body.

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.src = "http://somesite.com";

document.body.appendChild(iframe);
// request fired, your code would go here
```