# Can't get DOM of specific page

Tags: c#, .net, dom, browser

I've tried several solutions, and all of them failed in my tests.
I'm making a Form that reads the DOM of this page: http://www.kayak.com.br/flights#/NYC-DXB/2013-03-29-flexible/2013-04-17-flexible

This is an example, I'd like to automate the search of specific flights/dates. The page has multiple frames, I've tried:

- [WebBrowser Control in a new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269800/webbrowser-control-in-a-new-thread/4271581#4271581)
- [HTML - How do I know when all frames are loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672731/html-how-do-i-know-when-all-frames-are-loaded)
- [WebBrowser DocumentCompleted event fired more than once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3239204/webbrowser-documentcompleted-event-fired-more-than-once)
- [How to use WebBrowser control DocumentCompleted event in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840813/how-to-use-webbrowser-control-documentcompleted-event-in-c)
- [Detect WebBrowser complete page loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777878/detect-webbrowser-complete-page-loading)

All of the solutions in those links, none have worked.
Then I realized that "documentCompleted" event was not firing at the end of the progress bar, the last event was being fired before the flight search completed.

The only way I was able to get it was setting a timer for like 15s (assuming the research is complete), but this is not reliable at all!

This is my first post here, usually I find everything I need, but this time I think I'll need an extra help! :)

Comment: (Although I don't see a question in your post) Your page fills the table with javascript calls. so you can never be sure when these calls are finished. Your target side simply says *"Don't do it'*

Comment: I don't have a final code, I basically do:
- webbrowser.Navigate(url)
- GET final DOM? How?

Comment: what do you mean by `Then I realized that "documentCompleted" event was not firing at the end of the progress bar, the last event was being fired before the flight search completed.` ?