# How can you get your code to wait for html() and append() functions to complete?

Tags: jquery

I'm setting the html of the body element in an iframe to a string str, then I want to access that content on the next line (here just using an alert call to display the content) but the html and append functions haven't completed by the time the alert statement is called.

```
$(function(){
....
$("#notes-tab span.add_draft").bind("click", function(e){
    var str = '';
    $(this).parent().siblings(".tab-content").children(".para").each(function(ind) {
        str += $(this).find('div:first').html();
    });
    var curr = $("#content_rte").contents().find("body").html();
    if (curr == ' ' || curr == '<br>') {
        $("#content_rte").contents().find("body").html(str);
    }
    else {
        $("#content_rte").contents().find("body").append(str);
    }
    alert($("#content_rte").contents().find("body").html());
});
});
```

And of course neither the html nor the append functions take callbacks.

Could someone tell me how one normally accomplishes waiting for the DOM to be changed before proceeding?

Comment: Is this called from within your $(document).ready() function?

Answer (score -7, accepted):

There's really no direct method for waiting other than setting an arbitrary timeout before you attempt to retrieve the HTML.  The code to do so would be:

```
// wait for 250 ms, then try and retrieve contents
setTimeout(function() {
    alert($("#content_rte").contents().find("body").html());
}, 250);
```

You should try and make the timeout small enough to go unnoticed but large enough to allow for the contents to update, so you could get away with much less than 250ms.

Comment: Bad answer, you will never know what value to pick here. This will work for 99% of your customers and fail for that 1% that is actually bringing in most of the cash...

Comment: Yep, terrible answer, despite it may work for most cases.  What about race conditions? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)

Answer (score 11):

If you are using jQuery you can rely on [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to figure out if the element you just created has a parent `body` tag, and if it does it means it's been added to the DOM. You can write a function such as the following to allow you to actually do something when your element is ready:

```
callWhenReady: function (selector, callback, scope) {
    var self = this;
    if ($(selector).closest('body').length) {
        callback.call(scope);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            self.callWhenReady(selector, callback, scope);
        }, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this! You should add "`if (!$(selector).length) return;`" to the beginning to avoid infinite loops when the selector doesn't match any elements.

Answer (score 2):

`html` and `append` both call `domManip`, which is a synchronous method, so `alert` shouldn't even execute until those calls have completed.

Are you sure that the values you expect are being copied into the locations you expect?

Comment: Agreed.  @Craig, does the append happen successfully?

Also, append() returns jQuery.  You can get the html contents without searching a 2nd time.

Comment: Yes, bith the append and html write work successfully, after the alert shows a blank.

I didn't realise append returned anything.

Comment: @Craig, are you able to post a public link to your page or a version of the page that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @Jeff - IFRAME handling is tricky, I've experienced the same issue before.  It's probably worth a completely separate question to resolve exactly why retrieval fails (pertinent to IFRAMEs and the jQuery library itself).

Comment: @cballou - now I'm getting curious! I see there have been some other questions related to jquery and iframes (like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205087/jquery-ready-in-a-dynamically-inserted-iframe). Now to find some time ...

Comment: I have the same issue - so it's looks like command can be executed before 'append' call have completed.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [.ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/), which is "a way to run JavaScript code as soon as the page's Document Object Model (DOM) becomes safe to manipulate."

```
$('#yourID').html('new content').ready(function(){
    // Do stuffs
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the dom load event so that the iframe has time to finish loading:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var str = '<div>HelloWorld</div>';
    var curr = $("#content_rte").contents().find("body").html();
    if (curr == ' ' || curr == '<br>') {
        //$("#content_rte").contents().find("body").html(str);
        $("#content_rte").contents().find("body").append(str);
    }
    else {
        $("#content_rte").contents().find("body").append(str);
    }
    alert($("#content_rte").contents().find("body").html());
});
```

Comment: You may have to actually listen for the iframe's ready event ("#content_rte").contents().ready(fuction(){...});

Comment: it wouldnt be ready  it'd be load   ready defines full rendering of dom elements   load is both dom elements and content   thats what they need

Answer (score 0):

you should try $(window).load(function())  rather than document.ready     also   you could always fire the event after your appends. that way  the event(s) will only run once the append has successfully rendered.

the window.load only runs once the dom has loaded and then all content within the dom too.

if that doesnt work for you, then you could always have a setTimeout() run on the document.ready or window.load and put your functions/events in there and it will load after a specific amount of seconds.

you could try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var curr = $("#content_rte").contents().find("body").html();
    if (curr == ' ' || curr == '<br>') {
        $("#content_rte").contents().find("body").html(str);
    }
    else {
        $("#content_rte").contents().find("body").append(str);
    }
});
$(window).load(function(){
    alert($("#content_rte").contents().find("body").html());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$( document ).ready( function( ){ } )` or `$( function( ){ } )` but with that iframe's document element.

To do this, you can put your script into the iframe's HTML

```
theIframeHTMLContent += '<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>' +
                        '<script type="text/javascript">' +
                          '$( function( ){ alert( "I\'m ready!" ); } );' +
                        '</script>';

$( 'body' ).append( '<iframe id="cool"></iframe>' );
$( '#cool' ).html( theIframeHTMLContent );
```

Or you can try to do it on the newly appended iframe DOM element itself, but from the parent frame.  This is different across browsers, but the following example SHOULD work.

```
$( 'body' ).append( '<iframe id="cool"></iframe>' )
var theFrame = $( '#cool' )[ 0 ];
var docEl = theFrame.contentDocument || theFrame.contentWindow || theFrame.document;
$( docEl ).ready( function( ){ /* ready stuff */ } );
```

Tell me if I'm wrong, like I said, haven't tested this.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the [grancalavera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/824779/grancalavera)'s answer, but I used the lengh because my selector already exists in body... so:

```
var finalLength = $(selector).html().length + data.length;
$(selector).html(data); //or $(selector).append(data);
//...
callWhenReady: function (selector, callback, finalLength, scope) {
    var self = this;
    if ($(selector).html().length === finalLength) {
        callback.call(scope);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            self.callWhenReady(selector, callback, scope);
        }, 1);
    }
}
```