# Checking if iframe is ready to be written to

Tags: javascript, iframe, events, onload

A 3rd party script on my web page creates an iframe. I need to know when this iframe is ready, so I can manipulate its DOM.

I can think of a hacky approach: repeatedly try to modify the iFrame's DOM, and return success when a change we make sticks between two attempts. For this to work, I would prefer a property I can check on the iframe repeatedly.

Is there an alternative, cross-browser *evented* approach to knowing that the iframe is ready? E.g. can we redefine the onLoad function to call into our code (but I don't know if I can do this, since I didn't create the iframe).

Answer (score 2):

using jquery?

```
function callIframe(url, callback) {
    $(document.body).append('<IFRAME id="myId" ...>');
    $('iframe#myId').attr('src', url);

    $('iframe#myId').load(function() 
    {
        callback(this);
    });
}
```

Question answered in [jQuery .ready in a dynamically inserted iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205087/jquery-ready-in-a-dynamically-inserted-iframe)

Answer (score 1):

Have a variable in the parent:

```
var setToLoad = false;
```

Follow it up with a function to set it:

```
function SetToLoad() {
    setToLoad = true;
}
```

Then in the child iframe call this function using the window.opener

```
function CallSetToLoad() {
    window.opener.SetToLoad();
}

window.onload = CallSetToLoad;
```

This won't run until the iframe is finished loading, and if it's in the same domain it'll allow access to the opener. This would require editing a small portion of the 3rd party script.

EDIT: Alternative solution

Given that you can't edit the script, you might try something like:

```
frames["myiframe"].onload = function()
{
    // do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: This won't work for me, because I can't make changes to the 3rd party script (or ask for them)

Comment: Problem with load event with iframes is that it fires only after all images and subframes have loaded. A jQuery like ready function would be more useful.

Comment: @Tom: iFrames were a condition of the question, and given OP's limitations regarding the third party nature of the iFrame and scripts there-in, jQuery would have the same limitations in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Can you inject arbitrary scripting code into your iframe?  If so, you should be able to make it so that some code executes in the iframe upon the the iframe loading that calls code in the parent page.

Answer (score 0):

First: You probably won't be able to manipulate its dom when it loads html from other domain

And You probably are interested in DOMready. 
Look here:
[jQuery .ready in a dynamically inserted iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205087/jquery-ready-in-a-dynamically-inserted-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

Bilal,

There's a document.readyState property that you can check (works in IE).

```
foo(){
 if([your iframe id].document.readyState != "complete")
 {
   setTimeout("foo()", 500); //wait 500 ms then call foo
 }
 else
 {
   //iframe doc is ready
 }
}
```

Arkady