# iFrame inside Jquery accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a page that has an iFrame embedded inside a JQuery accordion.

JS:

```
$(function() {
                $("#doc_accordion").accordion();
        });
```

HTML:

```
  <div id="doc_accordion">
                    <h3><a href="#">1</a></h3>
                    <div>
                    <iframe src="http://test.com/view.do?url=http://test2.com/xyz" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                    </div>
                    <h3><a href="#">TESTING</a></h3>
                    <div>
                            <p>TESTING2</p>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

For some reason I can not see the embedded iFrame but I can see the accordion. Also if i remove the line  `$("#doc_accordion").accordion()` then I can see the iFrame correctly embedded in the page. Has anyone else experienced a similar problem?

Answer (score 2):

This I believe is because IE does not render children of hidden elements. As a workaround, you can load a 1px by 1px iframe outside the accordion and move it into the accordion once the iframe  has loaded. Here is an example:

```
<div id="widget-box"> <!-- Accordion -->
    <h3><a href="#">Widget</a></h3>
    <div id="widget-placeholder">            
    </div>
</div>

<iframe id='widget-frame' style="height:1px; width:1px;" src='widget.html'></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#widget-box").accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            autoHeight: false,
            active: false
        });
        $('#widget-frame').load(function () {
            if ($("#widget-placeholder > iframe").size() == 0) {
                $('#widget-placeholder').append($('#widget-frame'));
            }
            this.style.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
            this.style.width = '100%';
        });
    });
</script
```

>

Answer (score 0):

An option might be using the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#doc_accordion").accordion();
});
```

As far as I know the accordion hides the elements that are not shown, and this might interfere with the loading of the page into the Iframe.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205087/jquery-ready-in-a-dynamically-inserted-iframe might provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code & seems fine in Firefox & Safari on the Mac, and IE7 on the PC. I can see the iframe correctly. It's maybe a browser or CSS issue?

Have you tried declaring the width & height of the surrounding div tag as well? You can set it using a click() function. But in the meantime try adding 'style="width:600px; height:500px;"' to the div tag manually for now to test it.

It also may have something to do with what jQuery scripts you are using. I was using these two js scripts within the head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js" ></script>
```

I'm about to start experimenting with accordion & iframes myself (hence the interest)...