# JQUERY iFrame, Works with an Alert, doesn't work without an Alert - Strange? Why

Tags: jquery, iframe, binding, document-ready

The following does not work on my page:

```
$("#bob").ready(function () {
    $("#bob").contents().find(".findme").css("background", "red");

    $(document.getElementById('bob').contentWindow.document).find('.findme').bind("mousedown", function() {
        alert(  $(this).text() );
    });
});
```

But if I add an Alert, which I assume adds some type of delay to let the iframe run before JS continues, it DOES WORK?

```
$("#bob").ready(function () {
    alert(1)
    $("#bob").contents().find(".findme").css("background", "red");

    $(document.getElementById('bob').contentWindow.document).find('.findme').bind("mousedown", function() {
        alert(  $(this).text() );
    });
});
```

Is the delay is what's making it work, shouldn't the ready be taking care of this? Also, is there a way to make the above LIVE, so the timing isn't an issue?

Comment: See [jQuery .ready in a dynamically inserted iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205087/jquery-ready-in-a-dynamically-inserted-iframe).  It should work if you use `load` instead of `ready`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting that in a

$(document).ready(function() {

Instead of

$("#bob").ready(function () {