# Jquery. Execute code only when all iframes are loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

$(document).ready(handler)

call to handler when page is loaded not paying attention to whether iframes' content is loaded or not. I want code to be executed only when content of all iframes loaded.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Are the iframes on the same domain?

Comment: I used the .ready() function on upload iframes in previous projects. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help solve your problem:

[jQuery .ready in a dynamically inserted iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205087/jquery-ready-in-a-dynamically-inserted-iframe/205221#205221)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.load()` function to attach a callback to run when the iframe is loaded.

```
$('iframe.frame').load(function(){
    // do something...
});
```

Comment: That's for 1 iframe - what about multiple iframes (as the question states)?