# How to parse string html from submitted iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, file-upload, callback

I'm uploading a file in an iframe (with name and id=`upload_target`) to some server. As a response it creates a callback json style :

'result':'true'

So I'm trying the following. On `onload` action of my IFrame I've added an event listener, which should run function grabbing data :

```
function fileUploadFunction(){
    (...)
    $("#upload_target").onload = uploadDone;
    (...)        
};

function uploadDone() {
    alert("uploadDone");
    var ret = frames['upload_target'].document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML;
    var data = eval("("+ret+")");

    if(data.result == 'true') {
        alert("GREAT SUCCESS !!");            
    }
    else {
        alert("GREAT FAILURE :(");
    }   
}
```

But as a result I'm not getting anything at all. Should I return callback status in different form, or can it be solved differently ? Because even the first alert from uploadDone is not shown problem probably lies somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the reason nothing is happening is because of the funky way you have to detect an iFrame is loaded.  Check the post [jQuery .ready in a dynamically inserted iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205087/jquery-ready-in-a-dynamically-inserted-iframe).  I am assuming you are using jQuery.