# jQuery Event when New Page Loads in iFrame

Tags: jquery, events, iframe

I'm trying to set up an event on the parent that gets triggered when an iframe loads a new page (likely via the user clicking a link).

HTML:

```
<iframe name="posts" id="posts" src="edit.php">
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('iframe#posts').live('load', function() {
        console.log('live');
    });
});
```

The problem is that the `console.log()` statement never gets triggered. How can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that the 'load' event on the iframe has fired before the 'ready' event on the document, which means that the handler is installed too late. You may have to use the old-fashioned `onload` in the `iframe` element itself.

Or you could just put the `$('iframe#posts').live()` snippet in a top-level script rather than in the ready handler.

Comment: The old-school `<iframe onload="...">` worked great. I tried putting the `.live()` call in the global scope, but it still didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @dosboy makes sense, if Dan's guess is right. The iframe would still be getting triggered before the document.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to fix your problem is to have your iframe created with jQuery as well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("<iframe />").attr({
        id: "posts",
        src: "edit.php"
    }).load(function() {
        console.log('live');
    }).appendTo("body");
```

This question has been [asked here before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205087/jquery-ready-in-a-dynamically-inserted-iframe).

Answer (score 2):

The way I use is

```
<iframe onload="hide_html_player_contents_loading();" ...../>
```

Comment: < ifarme onload="hide_html_player_contents_loading();"