# How to make sure a page appears once the iFrame on the page has loaded first

Tags: php, iframe, loading

I'm pretty new to the world of web developing and web design in PHP, but I was hoping that someone could help me with my question.

I am loading a particular page on my PHP powered website which loads an iframe from another page elsewhere in the center of the page. I was wondering if anyone knows how to only get the whole page to load once the iframe has loaded. It's only a matter of a further one or two seconds before the iframe loads, but this needs to look as professional as possible.

I'd appreciate any help. I'd also like to assure you guys that although this is my first question, I know how Stack Overflow works as one of my best friends is a contributors here and he's always telling me how annoying it is when people don't respond or give points to good answers, so I'd like to assure you that I will do that.

Thanks again.
Steve.

Comment: Is the Page in the Iframe from the same domain ? Can you change Code there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JQuery.  You won't be able to do this in PHP, as it's a client side issue.

```
function callIframe(url, callback) {
    $(document.body).append('<IFRAME id="myId" ...>');
    $('iframe#myId').attr('src', url);

    $('iframe#myId').load(function() 
    {
        callback(this);
    });
}
```

See:
[jQuery .ready in a dynamically inserted iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205087/jquery-ready-in-a-dynamically-inserted-iframe)

Comment: Thank you profitphp, I'll try this tomorrow when I get into work and I'll let you know how I get on and grade you up :)