# Showing Ajax Progress Bar on Page load event

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, visual-studio-2010

In my project I need to show a Progress bar in the Page load event.
Basically I get a requiest from another application. Based on the request
My page will create a pdf file. As it will take time to create the pdf file
I need to display a progress bar or an animated gif image as the page is being created. 
Any idea how to do it. Remember I am not using any button_click events here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine something like this could work:

On document.ready have the gif image displayed by calling a function like this:

```
function ShowProgressBar(booleanValue)
{    if(booleanValue)
       $('#elementcontaingimage').show('slow');
     else 
       $('#elementcontaingimage').hide('slow');
}
```

with `true` parameter: `ShowProgressBar(true);`

And after the PDF is done being generated; just call something like:

```
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "key", "ShowProgressBar(false);", false);
```

But I have the feeling that it won't be as simple :S

**UPDATE -  working example**

I figured out a way to make it work but you will need to separate the code that generates the PDF into a different page whose only purpose will be to write the PDF file to the response stream. Better yet, you could write an HttpHandler to write the PDF file to the Response Stream but for the purposes of this example, I'll write the PDF file from a regular aspx page.

**Step 1**: Insert the following markup and javascript code in your page.

```
 <div id="imageDiv">
        <img alt="" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />
    </div>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function ShowProgressBar(booleanValue) {
            if (booleanValue) {
                $('#imageDiv').show('slow');
                createIframe();
            }
            else 
                $('#imageDiv').hide('slow');

        }
        function callback(parent) {
            ShowProgressBar(false);
        }
        function createIframe() {
            $('<iframe />', {
                name: 'myFrame',
                id: 'myFrame',
                src: 'PageGeneratingPDF.aspx',
                style: 'display:none;'
            }).appendTo('body').load(function () {
                callback(this);
            });
        }
        window.onload = ShowProgressBar(true);
    </script>
```

**Explanation**: On page load ShowProgressBar is called to start displaying an animated gif image. The following line `-createIframe();-` creates an `iframe` dynamically and sets the `src` attribute to be the url of the page that will write the PDF to the Response Stream. It then appends the `iframe` to the page `body` and attaches a `callback` function that will be invoked when the `iframe` is done loading. Since the `callback` function is called when  `PageGeneratingPDF.aspx` is finished generating the PDF file, the only thing left for the `callback` function to do is hide the div containing the animated gif image.

The `PageGeneratingPDF.aspx` code behind could look something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread.Sleep(10000);//Give the sensation that the pdf file takes long to generate
    //replace line below with actual code that generates the PDF file
    byte[] pdf = File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath(@"~/file.pdf"));
    Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=report.pdf");
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.BinaryWrite(pdf);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();        
}
```

You are done. The output will be something like this.

Initially...

[image: first page]

After generating the PDF...

[image: second image]

[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205087/jquery-ready-in-a-dynamically-inserted-iframe) in StackOverflow, was very helpful.

Comment: Hi Icarus, Its not working. The image is loading after the pdf is generated(which is after 10 secs). But I want to show the loading image while pdf is generated.

Comment: @Henry I just posted a working example. Let me know if you implement it.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. That was really helpful. You wrote the entire code for me. Much appreciated your help.