# Getting and modifying iframe content with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I want to add markup to the the iframe's body tag. Following code can do it but only if iframe content object is inside of click event. Here's example:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    var tinymceFrame = $('#editor_ifr').contents().find('#tinymce');

    $('body').on('click', 'button', function() {
        $(tinymceFrame).append('<img class="widgetty" title="Widget" src="" />');
    });
});
```

This won't work but if I move tinymceFrame line inside click event it will work.

Also after image is added to iframe's body tag how to trigger on click event on that image?
I tried something like:

```
$(tinymceFrame).on('click', '.widgetty', function() {
    alert('test');
});
```

Comment: I think, *think*, this is because the content of the iframe is not loaded yet. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205087/jquery-ready-in-a-dynamically-inserted-iframe

Comment: Thank you, following answer by David Valentiate helped solving the problem.