# Remove Class after iframe load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to remove class hidden after the iframe load, My code http://jsfiddle.net/rzP5S/3/ , I tried to use .ready() but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<iframe onload="removeClass();" ... />
```

Edit:

Related thread at stackoverflow: [jQuery .ready in a dynamically inserted iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205087/jquery-ready-in-a-dynamically-inserted-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$(window).load(function () {
 //Use removeClass() here
 $('#contentpage').children().removeClass('onePost');
});
```

Comment: I dont see the point, isint the code already inside shorthand of jquery document ready? http://rdjs.co.uk/jquery-document-ready-alternatives/53