# How can I detect whether an iframe is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to check whether an iframe has loaded after the user clicks a button.

I have

```
$('#MainPopupIframe').load(function(){
    console.log('load the iframe')
    //the console won't show anything even if the iframe is loaded.
})
```

HTML

```
<button id='click'>click me</button>

//the iframe is created after the user clicks the button.
<iframe id='MainPopupIframe' src='http://...' />...</iframe>
```

Any suggestions?

By the way, my iframe is created dynamically. It doesn’t load with the initial page load.

Comment: [Click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205087/jquery-ready-in-a-dynamically-inserted-iframe)

Answer (score 189, accepted):

You may try this (using `jQuery`)

```js
$(function(){
    $('#MainPopupIframe').load(function(){
        $(this).show();
        console.log('iframe loaded successfully')
    });
        
    $('#click').on('click', function(){
        $('#MainPopupIframe').attr('src', 'https://heera.it');    
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='click'>click me</button>

<iframe style="display:none" id='MainPopupIframe' src='' /></iframe>
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/umYkV/).

**Update:** Using plain `javascript`

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var ifr = document.getElementById('MainPopupIframe');
    ifr.onload=function(){
        this.style.display='block';
        console.log('laod the iframe')
    };

    var btn = document.getElementById('click');    
    btn.onclick=function(){
        ifr.src='https://heera.it';    
    };
};
```

```html
<button id='click'>click me</button>

<iframe style="display:none" id='MainPopupIframe' src='' /></iframe>
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/umYkV/1/).

**Update:** Also you can try this (dynamic iframe)

```js
$(function(){
    $('#click').on('click', function(){
        var ifr = $('<iframe/>', {
            id:'MainPopupIframe',
            src:'https://heera.it',
            style:'display:none;width:320px;height:400px',
            load:function(){
                $(this).show();
                alert('iframe loaded !');
            }
        });
        $('body').append(ifr);    
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='click'>click me</button><br />
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/umYkV/121/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sheikh. However, I don't have MainpopupIframe elements available when the page is loaded. The MainpopipIframe was create after the user clicks the button. so .load function doesn't work on my case. Anyway to archive the result i needed? Thanks. +1

Comment: @Rouge, try the updated answer. You may like this. Thanks :-)

Comment: @SheikhHeera : how to check if it is not loaded, sothat i can insert the source .....if(iframe_loaded){do nothing...}else{insert the src for iframe}

Comment: `load()` is deprecated, but that's just because it was conflicting with the ajax function.  The recommended replacement is simply `on("load")`.  (Unfortunately, the docs don't quite make clear that that's all you need to do.)

Comment: Recommended for what?  It is the only way I know for JQuery to attach a load listener (as opposed to `.click`, `.change`, etc., which are aliases of their corresponding `on` counterpart).

Comment: @TheAlpha what's the best way to check if the iFrame loaded successfully?  E.g. server is busy, 404 not found, other errors, etc.  In this case, the src for the iFrame is the same as the domain of the parent page.  I have access to all the iFrames' src.

Comment: @vanowm, Which one? Vanilla or jQuery? Can you please collaborate?

Answer (score 2):

I imagine this like that:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var frame_loaded = 0;
function setFrameLoaded()
{
   frame_loaded = 1;
   alert("Iframe is loaded");
}
$('#click').click(function(){
   if(frame_loaded == 1)
    console.log('iframe loaded')
   } else {
    console.log('iframe not loaded')
   }
})
</script>
</head>
<button id='click'>click me</button>

<iframe id='MainPopupIframe' onload='setFrameLoaded();' src='http://...' />...</iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try onload event as well;

```
var createIframe = function (src) {
        var self = this;
        $('<iframe>', {
            src: src,
            id: 'iframeId',
            frameborder: 1,
            scrolling: 'no',
            onload: function () {
                self.isIframeLoaded = true;
                console.log('loaded!');
            }
        }).appendTo('#iframeContainer');

    };
```