# How do I detect when an iframe starts loading and when it finishes loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project where I upload files using an `iframe`.

I need to show a pre-loader when the `iframe` starts uploading the file and hide the pre-loader when the `iframe` finishes loading.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Is it on the same domain?

Comment: yes it is on the some domain

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect if the iframe is loaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267010/how-to-detect-if-the-iframe-is-loaded)

Comment: better show some rough structure so we can follow and suggest. Basically, preloader gif can be set up in the page embedded in iframe. Unless you have more complicated file / code structure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution:

this is parent document of Iframe:

```
<div id="loader"></div>
<div class="iframeClass">
    <iframe src="myIframe.php" id="myIframe" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('myIframe').onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
```

this is iframe document:

```
<form action="myIframe.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myForm">
<input type="file" name="myFile" id="myFile" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('myFile').onchange = function() {
        top.document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
    }
</script>
```

enjoy guys  :)))

Answer (score 0):

You can try following jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
alert("Iframe Start Loading ...");
       var ifr=$('<iframe></iframe>', {
            id:'frame',
            src:'http://ernagroup.com',
            style:'display:none',
            load:function(){
                $(this).show();
                alert('iframe loaded !');
            }
        });
        $('body').append(ifr);
});
```