# Pass document.ready() of iframe to parent container

Tags: jquery, dom, iframe, shadowbox

Is there a way to pass the `document.ready()` of an iframe to the parent container?

My scenario is this:

External content is shown in an iframe in a Shadowbox. The shadowbox overlay (`#sb-overlay`) has a background with a loading icon. I now would like to remove the loading icon, when the content in the iframe has completely loaded.

Thanks!

Comment: I think youre answer is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267010/how-can-i-detect-whether-an-iframe-is-loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code, that got it working for me:

```
$('.iframelink').on('click', function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('iframe').load(function(){
            $('#sb-overlay').css('background-image','none');
            console.log('loaded');
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('iframe#iframeid').load(function() {
    //hide the loading
});
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205087/jquery-ready-in-a-dynamically-inserted-iframe) post, for iframes the `load` event is good enough. No need to implement `document.ready`.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not working like this. Nothing happens with this code.