# Opening another URL in iFrame loading event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a iFrame and it is loading dynamically with

```
$("#myFrame").attr('src', url);
```

There are many links inside the iframe.While clicking on any link it loads another URL automatically.I want to show spin (load...) image in between opening a new URL. I've tried below

```
$('#myFrame').load(function(){ });
```

But above executes once frame is loaded with new URL.I want to track before load complete event.How can I track duration when frame is in loading state.
Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I detect whether an iframe is loaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267010/how-can-i-detect-whether-an-iframe-is-loaded)

Comment: I do not want to use click event as there are many links and few of them are based on JS ( no new url window)