# detect when iframe content has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, reactjs, orbeon

So i have a small react component which renders an iframe. I need to determine when all the content (html etc) has fully loaded.

The iframe is loading an orbeon form which can takes a few seconds to fully load.

I have tried hooking into the 'load' event form the iframe which works but triggers the even the second the iframe is loaded and not when the iframes content has loaded.

I have read some posts about listening to the 'DOMContentLoaded' even but cannot seem to get that to work.

here is the react component which renders the Iframe.

basically I need to trigger the documentDrawerLoaded function once all of the iframe content has been rendered.

```
return React.createClass({
        displayName: 'FilePickerColourSelector',

        getInitialState: function() {
            return {
                listVisible: false
            };
        },

        componentWillMount: function () {
            console.log('loading...')
        },

        componentDidMount: function () {
        this.refs.documentDrawer.getDOMNode().addEventListener('load', this.documentDrawerLoaded);

        },

        documentDrawerLoaded: function () {
            console.log('drawer has been loaded');
            document.getElementById('js-document-drawer-overlay').classList.toggle('active');
            document.getElementById('js-document-drawer').classList.toggle('active');
        },

        render: function() {
            var documentDrawerStyles = {
                height: '100%',
                width: '100%',
                border: 'none'
            }

            return <iFrame 
                        src={this.props.url} 
                        style={documentDrawerStyles} 
                        ref="documentDrawer"
                        scrolling="no"
                    >
                    </iFrame>;
        },

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are controlling the content of the iframe you may use [cross-origin communication](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). Or in other words the site in your iframe knows when its content is fully loaded and broadcast that information to the parent page.

Answer (score -4):

You can use Jquery for that:

```
$(function(){
    $('#MainPopupIframe').on('load', function(){
        $(this).show();
        console.log('load the iframe')
    });

    $('#click').on('click', function(){
        $('#MainPopupIframe').attr('src', 'http://heera.it');    
    });
});
```

as see in the example:
[How can I detect whether an iframe is loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267010/how-can-i-detect-whether-an-iframe-is-loaded)

Comment: I mentioned in the OP that I have already tried the 'on.load()' event. It doesn't tell me when all of the content within the iFrame has loaded.

Comment: Even when you especify the iframe to look?

Comment: yup seems to be unless I have been doing something wrong.

Comment: You try using, like in the example, with a dynamic content: Update: Also you can try this (dynamic iframe)

$(function(){
    $('#click').on('click', function(){
        var ifr=$('<iframe/>', {
            id:'MainPopupIframe',
            src:'http://heera.it',
            style:'display:none',
            load:function(){
                $(this).show();
                alert('iframe loaded !');
            }
        });
        $('body').append(ifr);    
    });
});

Comment: hmm ill give that a try later on. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Try to use this example to, is for React code: https://developer.zendesk.com/blog/rendering-to-iframes-in-react

Comment: as cool as that is its not for rendering external content, its for wrapping a react component inside an iframe.