# How can i check whether the content in iframe loaded in angular 7?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, user-interface, iframe

How can i check whether the content in iframe loaded in **angular 7**? I tried (load) event but which called before iframe load complete (in fact it called two times, first when i clicked on link which shows iframe. Second when iframe loaded).

I have to show spinner till iframe load completely. unable to check whether the iframe loaded or not. I can not use jquery here. Any way to check this using angular 7 ?

Comment: Hi, one available solution use plain javascript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47704971/5272951

Comment: One more simpler: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9249734/5272951