# JavaScript inside iframe doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, frame

I try to show this page inside iframe:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.mobile-1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.js"/>"></script>
    <link href="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.mobile-1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.css"/>" rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css"/>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            $('#listView').listview();
        });
    </script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" id="listView">
        <li><a href="index.html">Inbox <span class="ui-li-count">12</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Outbox <span class="ui-li-count">0</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Drafts <span class="ui-li-count">4</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Sent <span class="ui-li-count">328</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Trash <span class="ui-li-count">62</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This page contains some javascript that must be executed for applying style within this page (not in the parent page). But it simply doesn't work. Page looks like simple html. 
What I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are including jQuery Mobile on the page, you also need to include the jQuery plugin before that.  You should be getting a JavaScript error that jQuery is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `jQuery(document).ready` part is firing before the iframe actually gets loaded.  If that's right, you'll have to do a custom function to handle it.  You can find something like that here: [jQuery .ready in a dynamically inserted iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205087/jquery-ready-in-a-dynamically-inserted-iframe).