# How change this iframe content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

sample main page for example **index.html** content  :

```
<iframe src="a.html" width="400" height="300" frameborder="1" id="frame"></iframe>
```

**a.html** content :

```
<html><body><form >
<div id="container"><div id="main"><div class="red_bl"><div class="red_br">
<div class="red_tl"><div class="red_tr"><div id="content">

<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
<tbody id="subContent1">
<tr>another tags</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2" class="cell2" valign="top">
sample text
</td>
<td id="td_address" class="cell3">sample code</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>


</div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
</form></body></html>
```

i want change :

```
<td id="td_address" class="cell3">sample code</td>
```

to for example :

```
<td id="td_address" class="cell3">another text</td>
```

by jQuery In **index.html**  .

Comment: frame.td_address.innerHTML="another text";

Comment: Are the two pages (iframe and outer page) on the same domain? If not, this isn't possible due to the same origin policy

Comment: @Basic: the url is visible in the iframe tag...

Comment: what ?!!! i said by jquery  and not worked this code(this is bad code) @dandavis

Comment: yes two pages are on same damain  and url visible in the iframe tag but not worked this code because not changed sample code text

Comment: @dandavis quite often posters simplify their problem for SO. I was hoping to make sure the question hadn't been over-simplified (based on the fact that the answer below which should work apparently doesn't)

Comment: the code i posted worked for me. i only tried chrome. i'm sure there are way to make it more complicated, but i don't believe the problem lies with either code you've been given...

Comment: but my problem not  solved yet and not worked

Comment: @barnameha:  show us the current fiddle.

Comment: my english language is not good whats your means of current fiddle ?!!! if u want i can upload 2 pages on my site to can see it

Comment: your code, my code, working together for all to see: http://danml.com/b.html

Comment: i am trying to open http://danml.com/b.html but i can not yet

Comment: here direct link on my site : http://demo.barnameha.net/upload/main.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `document.ready` doesn't wait for the `iframe` to load.

Therefore, the code that you run is executed before `#td_address` is added to DOM.

For various solutions to this problem (depending on what are you able to change), look at answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205087/jquery-ready-in-a-dynamically-inserted-iframe).

Answer (score 1):

With JQuery:

```
$('#frame').contents().find('td#td_address').html('another text');
```

Comment: Works if pages are on same server. instead of opening file, put page on some web server (iis, apache etc.) and test.

Comment: i said to @dandavis , two pages are on same server and two pages is easy pages(html + jquery code only not php code or another service pages), and my problem not solved yet and not worked

Comment: @barnameha please post your complete code (both HTML pages and all JavaScript).

Comment: i added alert u can see now

Comment: deleted my comment as it was misleading. See my answer for explanation.