# Triggering Javascript inside dynamically created iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently building a chrome extension, in which I've managed to make a pop-up using an Iframe, whenever a user click on a button of my chrome extension.

Inside of my iFrame I'm loading 2 .js files: jQuery and "modal.js" from the chrome extension.
Doing an inspect I can see that the file is loaded (modal.js), however I'm using the following code, which is not triggered:

```
  $('#frameID').ready(function(){
    $('#sbm-new-group').click(function(){
      console.log("hello");
     });
  });
```

This is not working, and even if I try using $(document).ready, nothing fires up. I'd like to know if there's anyway in triggering the method using the javascript inside the iFrame.

Any help is greately appreciated.

Comment: Not enough information to diagnose the problem. What is `#sbm-modal`?

Comment: I've edited it, it is the ID of the iFrame.

Comment: Are you using a Content Script to inject into the browser page iteself, or are you using the standard Chrome browser_action:default_popup definition?

Comment: Remember that an `<iframe>` wraps it's own independent _#document_ and _Window_, to access inside you need to go via e.g. `ifrm.contentWindow`

Comment: Abe: Yes, I'm using a content script to load the iframe.
Paul: That's what I need help with, I don't understand how to "trigger" when the iframe shows up, simulating a document.ready inside the JS of my iFrame

Comment: Maybe this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205087/jquery-ready-in-a-dynamically-inserted-iframe

Comment: Your link doesn't seem to load :(, but I believe I already tried using the code in that question, however I could not get it to work as it is not a "duplicate", it is just very similar

Comment: @PaulS. that can and should be expanded to an answer probably.

Comment: Although, since you're writing a chrome extension, you (OP) should just use the background page for messaging between the frames.

Comment: I think the question can be reduced to: Can I run a javascript file contained in the iFrame? If so, how can I bind "on-click" events, or document.ready?

Comment: Please clarify: how are you injecting the script, and how can you see that the file is loaded? (in the correct frame)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should access the iframe's `document` to bind the `.ready()` handler.
Here is a [**demo fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/onury/8yM7u/).

***Note:*** This is possible if you're on the same domain.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('frameID'),
    iframeWin = iframe.contentWindow || iframe,
    iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframeWin.document;

$(iframeDoc).ready(function (event) {
    alert('iframe ready');
    // now you can access any element in the iframe (if same domain)
    $(iframeDoc).find('#sbm-new-group').on('click', function (event) {
         alert('clicked');
    });
});
```

[Edit] **Extra Notes:**

- To call a function in the ***owner*** global scope, **from the iframe document**:

  `parent.someMethod();`
- To call a function in the ***iframe*** global scope, **from the owner document**:

  `iframeWin.someMethod();`
- To execute scripts within the ***iframe***, **from the owner document**:

```js
// this is called from the iframe
window.hello = function () {
    alert('hello from owner!');
};

// we'll write some scripts within the iframe that will be executed immediately
iframeDoc.open();
iframeDoc.write('\<script>alert("hello from iframe!");\<\/script>');
iframeDoc.write('\<script>parent.hello();\<\/script>');
iframeDoc.close();
```

Here is [**another fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/onury/ALHGP/) demonstrating this one.

Comment: WARNING: you can't do this when it's coming from another domain.

Comment: Question: how could I trigger something like a $(document).keyup event?

Comment: You can do it the same way shown in the example: `$(iframeDoc).on('keyup', function (event) { console.log(event.keyCode); });`

Comment: Is this the "cleanest" way to do it? I was trying to avoid binding events using $(iframeDoc).find... thinking there might be a cleaner way.

Comment: From the owner document, if you want to (a) know when the iframe document is ready; (b) manipulate the iframe DOM from the owner document; -- this is the way to do it. I've added some extra notes in the answer, regarding executing scripts / calling functions.