# Javascript or Jquery: Write html to iframe not fire $(document).ready in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, onload, ready

This is my situation.

The main page:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function load_frm()
    {
        if($.browser.msie == true) {
            var frame = document.getElementById('frm');
            frame.contentWindow.document.write(patch_html);
        }
        else {
            $("#frm").attr('src', "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + escape(patch_html));
        }
    }
</script>
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <input type="button" onclick="load_frm()">
    <iframe id="frm"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

the patch_html contain $(document).ready which is need to fire after iframe loaded completely to **change some element style inside the iframe**.

jquery is included in header of patch_html.
This code worked fine in firefox but not in IE.

The reason why I had to use write (for IE) and attr('src', "data:text/html...") is the html doesn't have the **script to change some element style**, it only injected in some certain conditions

I'm tried iframe's onLoad but it doesn't work. it fired before the resource loaded completely.

---

I founded the answer:
[javascript-how-to-load-dynamic-contents-html-string-json-to-iframe](http://www.zomeoff.com/javascript-how-to-load-dynamic-contents-html-string-json-to-iframe/)

I think the problem is

```js
iframedoc.open();
iframedoc.writeln(patch_html);
iframedoc.close();
```

*the document need to **open/close** probably.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded the answer: javascript-how-to-load-dynamic-contents-html-string-json-to-iframe

I think the problem is

```js
iframedoc.open();
iframedoc.writeln(patch_html);
iframedoc.close();
```

the document need to **open/close** probably.

Answer (score 0):

Probably use:-

```
 $('iframe#frm').load(function() {/*do something here*/});
```

[Here is the post which will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205087/jquery-ready-in-a-dynamically-inserted-iframe).