# Holy grail for determining whether or not local iframe has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Firstly, I see this question asked a few times but no answers seem satisfactory. What I am looking for is to be able to call a script at anytime and determine whether or not an iframe has loaded - and to not limit the script to require being added to the iframe tag itself in an onload property.

Here's some background: I have been working on an unobtrusive script to try and determine whether or not local iframes in the dom have loaded, this is because one of our clients includes forms on their website in iframes and many of them open in lightboxes - which dynamically add the iframes into the dom at any time.  I can attach to the open event of the lightbox, but its hit or miss as to whether I can "catch" the iframe before it has loaded.

Let me explain a little more.

In my testing I've determined that the onload event will only fire once - and only if it is bound before the iframe actually loads. For example:  This page should only alert "added to iframe tag" and the listener that is attached afterward does not fire - to me that makes sense. (I'm using the iframe onload property for simple example).

https://jsfiddle.net/g1bkd3u1/2/

```
<script>
    function loaded () {
        alert ("added to iframe tag");
        $("#test").load(function(){
            alert("added after load finished");
        });
    };
</script>
<iframe onload="loaded()" id="test" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Frames"></iframe>
```

My next approach was to check the document ready state of the iframe which seems to work in almost all of my testing except chrome which reports "complete" - I was expecting "Access Denied" for cross domain request. I'm ok with a cross domain error because I can disregard the iframe since I am only interested in local iframes - firefox reports "unintialized" which I'm ok with because I know I can then attach an onload event.

Please open in Chrome:
https://jsfiddle.net/g1bkd3u1/

```
<iframe id="test" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Frames"></iframe>
<script>
    alert($("#test").contents()[0].readyState);
</script>
```

I've found that if I wait just 100ms - then the iframe seems to report as expected (a cross domain security exception - which is what I want - but I don't want to have to wait an arbitrary length).

https://jsfiddle.net/g1bkd3u1/4/

```
<iframe id="test" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Frames"></iframe>
<script>
    setTimeout(function () { 
        try {
            alert($("#test").contents()[0].readyState);
        } catch (ignore) {
            alert("cross domain request");
        }
    }, 100);
</script>
```

My current workaround / solution is to add the onload event handler, then detach the iframe from the dom, then insert it back into the dom in the same place - now the onload event will trigger. Here's an example that waits 3 seconds (hoping thats enough time for the iframe to load) to show that detaching and re-attaching causes the iframe onload event to fire.

https://jsfiddle.net/g1bkd3u1/5/

```
<iframe id="test" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Frames"></iframe>
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){
        var placeholder = $("<span>");
        $("#test").load(function(){
            alert("I know the frame has loaded now");
        }).after(placeholder).detach().insertAfter(placeholder);
        placeholder.detach();
    }, 3000);
</script>
```

While this works it leaves me wondering if there are better more elegant techniques for checking iframe load (unobtrusively)?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today I actually ran into a bug where my removing and re-inserting of iframes was breaking a wysiwyg editor on a website. So I created the start of a small jQuery plugin to check for iframe readiness. It is not production ready and I have not tested it much, but it should provide a nicer alternative to detaching and re-attaching an iframe - it does use polling if it needs to, but should remove the setInterval when the iframe is ready.

It can be used like:

```
$("iframe").iready(function() { ... });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q0smjkh5/10/

```
<script>
  (function($, document, undefined) {
    $.fn["iready"] = function(callback) {
      var ifr = this.filter("iframe"),
          arg = arguments,
          src = this,
          clc = null, // collection
          lng = 50,   // length of time to wait between intervals
          ivl = -1,   // interval id
          chk = function(ifr) {
            try {
              var cnt = ifr.contents(),
                  doc = cnt[0],
                  src = ifr.attr("src"),
                  url = doc.URL;
              switch (doc.readyState) {
                case "complete":
                  if (!src || src === "about:blank") {
                    // we don't care about empty iframes
                    ifr.data("ready", "true");
                  } else if (!url || url === "about:blank") {
                    // empty document still needs loaded
                    ifr.data("ready", undefined);
                  } else {
                    // not an empty iframe and not an empty src
                    // should be loaded
                    ifr.data("ready", true);
                  }

                  break;
                case "interactive":
                  ifr.data("ready", "true");
                  break;
                case "loading":
                default:
                  // still loading
                  break;   
              }
            } catch (ignore) {
              // as far as we're concerned the iframe is ready
              // since we won't be able to access it cross domain
              ifr.data("ready", "true");
            }

            return ifr.data("ready") === "true";
          };

      if (ifr.length) {
        ifr.each(function() {
          if (!$(this).data("ready")) {
            // add to collection
            clc = (clc) ? clc.add($(this)) : $(this);
          }
        });
        if (clc) {
          ivl = setInterval(function() {
            var rd = true;
            clc.each(function() {
              if (!$(this).data("ready")) {
                if (!chk($(this))) {
                  rd = false;
                }
              }
            });

            if (rd) {
              clearInterval(ivl);
              clc = null;
              callback.apply(src, arg);
            }
          }, lng);
        } else {
          clc = null;
          callback.apply(src, arg);
        }
      } else {
        clc = null;
        callback.apply(this, arguments);
      }
      return this;
    };
  }(jQuery, document));
</script>
```

The example waits until the window has loaded to dynamically add an iframe to the DOM, it then alerts its document's readyState - which in chrome displays "complete", incorrectly. The iready function should be called after and an attempt to output the document's readyState proves cross domain exception - again this has not been thoroughly tested but works for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue in that I had an iframe and needed to modify its' document once it had finished loading.

**IF** you know or can control the content of the loaded document in the iFrame, then you could simply check for/add an element that you could check the existence of in order to then update the iframe document.
At least then you know the elements you want to work with are loaded in to the document.

In my case, I called a function, which itself checked for the existence of my known element that would always be found after the elements I needed to update had already been loaded - in the case it was not found, it called itself again through setTimeout().

```
function updateIframeContents() {
    if ($("#theIframe").contents().find('.SaveButton').length > 0) {
        // iframe DOM Manipulation
    } else {
        setTimeout(updateIframeContents, 250);
    }
}

updateIframeContents();
```