# Hide element inside iframe by classname

Tags: jquery, css, iframe

I'm using iframe on a popup window. And I want to hide a div by classname from iframe. This popup opens when user intend to exist.

My code:

```
<div class="lightbox">
  <div class="box">
      <iframe id="my_iframe" src="mydomain.com" style="width:500px; min-height:400px; height:auto;"  frameborder="0"></iframe>
      
        <p> <a href="#" class="close">X</a></p>
  </div>
</div>

$('#my_iframe').ready(function(){
console.log('load the iframe')
var $poweredWrapper = $('#my_iframe').find("poweredWrapper");
$poweredWrapper.hide();
});
```

How can I hide div with this class  `poweredWrapper`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

poweredWrapper is your class name, so call it by classname, instead you are calling it as element.
use:

```
var $poweredWrapper = $('#my_iframe').content().find(".poweredWrapper");
```

instead:

```
var $poweredWrapper = $('#my_iframe').find("poweredWrapper");
```

Comment: Tried with that also. Not working.

Comment: did you console `$poweredWrapper`, is it returning anything?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/U8MyaBJHexqb

Nothing without this load the iframe.

Comment: I have edited the above answer, try it out, hopefully it will work for you.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/kECS2MWp2tYf

I want to hide mailchimp copyright logo from an iframe.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).content is not a function

showing this error with your updated answer

Comment: someone has answered in this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205087/jquery-ready-in-a-dynamically-inserted-iframe], i guess your `$('#id').ready` is not working.