# How to remove div when iframe fully loaded with jQuery

Tags: jquery, iframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript callback when IFRAME is finished loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164085/javascript-callback-when-iframe-is-finished-loading)

Is there any way to wait until an iframe has fully loaded before removing a div?

I'm using the following:

```
  $("#myButton").click(function(event){
        $('#response').html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' border=0> Please Wait - Loading!");
        $("#myIFrame").attr('src', $('#url').val());
  });
```

I'd like to remove the loading gif once the iFrame fully loads.

Any ideas?!

Thanks!!!

Comment: are you using AJAX currently in your application? What language other than java script are you using? There may be a better way in general to do this.

Comment: fyi I updated my answer with a more complete code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the load event on your iframe:

```
 $("#myButton").click(function(event){
        $('#response').html("<span id='loader'><img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' border=0> Please Wait - Loading!</span>");
        $("#myIFrame").attr('src', $('#url').val());
  });

  $('#myIFrame').load(function(){
    $("#loader").remove();
  });
```