# Is it possible to edit DOM elements that get loaded via an <iframe> with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

I have the following HTML code:

```
<body>
  ...
  <div id="users">
      <iframe src="http://control.intranet/userlist.php" height="100">
  </div>
  ...
</body>
```

Where the `//control.intranet/userlist.php` loads a list of users from our intranet control panel.

This list looks like this:

```
<div class="user">
    <span class="name">Boda Cydo</span>
    <span class="ip">10.42.12.2</span>
    ...
</div>
<div class="user">
     ...
</div>
...
```

Now I want to format how the userlist looks, so I try to match elements in it with jQuery:

```
$("#users .name").css("background-color", "#FF0000")
```

But it never matches a single `.name`.

I even tried just `$("#users").length` and it returns 0.

This makes me think that I can't edit DOM elements loaded via iframe with jQuery. Is that true? If so, how do I edit CSS of elements that are loaded via iframe?

Thanks, Boda Cydo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript callback when IFRAME is finished loading?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164085/javascript-callback-when-iframe-is-finished-loading)

Comment: Is the parent page also hosted on `control.intranet`? If not, this is complicated by cross-domain security issues.

Comment: It's on `monitor.extranet`, can i access the iframe of `control.intranet` from it?

Answer (score 3):

> The .contents() method can also be
>   used to get the content document of an
>   iframe, if the iframe is on the same
>   domain as the main page.

From: http://api.jquery.com/contents/

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$("#iframeid").contents().("#users .name").css("background-color", "#FF0000");
```

it will only work if your iframe and main page belongs to same domain.

Comment: Is there any way to go cross-domain?

Answer (score 0):

Quick googling gave me : http://simple.procoding.net/2008/03/21/how-to-access-iframe-in-jquery/