# How could I use Javascript to download HTML file that i have edited the DOM of and keep the changes that i have done in the downloaded file?

Tags: javascript, iframe, download

Im going to try to explain better what I want to solve here :) 
Im making a small web-app that let you download a preset for a HTML code. You fill in some forms and this get stored in a variable that later get used to change the DOM of an Iframed HTML file. Is it possible to download this file and keep the changes ived done with Javascript?

What I have tried so far:

```
    let fileHref = 'preset.html';
    var anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.setAttribute("download", downloadName);
    anchor.setAttribute("href", fileHref);
    anchor.click();
```

But of course as i figured i would get the plain HTML file without the changes. Is there any way to do this with vanilla JS? Im totally lost here.

Comment: There may be an answer to your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797099/is-it-possible-to-edit-dom-elements-that-get-loaded-via-an-iframe-with-jquery 


If you want to edit the contents of an iFrame, both pages need to be in the same domain.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I get to change the content of the Iframe, but i want to download the edited file with the changes i have done. This is where I think it can become difficult