# How to perform function after Jquery (window).load is complete

Tags: jquery, load

I'm trying fade in a div after an iframe has loaded. The iframe is being called after the window has loaded.

I can load the iframe fine but I can't figure out how to make the div fadeIn *after* the load has completed. Thanks ahead for your assistance.

This is what I've tried but the load function following the html isn't happening

```
$(function() {
    $(window).load( function() {
        $("#ad").html("<iframe ... </iframe>").load(function(){
            $("#ad").fadeIn("normal");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Javascript callback when IFRAME is finished loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164085/javascript-callback-when-iframe-is-finished-loading)

Answer (score 0):

Set your `#ad` to `display:none;` by default. Then try the following.

```
$(function() {
    $(window).load( function() {
        $("#ad").html("<iframe ... </iframe>").fadeIn("normal");       
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried this with a 3000 ms fadeIn, but it didn't appear to work. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a handle on the iframe's window object and then check document.readyState to see if the load event has already fired. If it has, it will equal "complete".

Something like this:

```
$('<iframe>').attr('src', '/pow.html').appendTo(document.body);
var win = window[window.length - 1];

var fn = function () { console.log('loaded!') };
$(win).load(fn);
if (win.document.readyState === "complete") fn();
```