# Why doesn't this jquery code work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iframe

```
 $('#iframe').ready(function() {
   $('#iframe a').attr('target', '_parent');
 });
```

simple as that.

EDIT:

my html:

```
 <div id='outerdiv'>
   <iframe src="http://localhost:8888/harvest/blog" id='iframe' scrolling=no></iframe>
 </div>
```

Comment: Could you provide some example markup, possibly on jsfiddle or similiar?

Comment: is the element you're targeting and actual iframe?  and if so, are you wanting the attributes to be set after that iframe's contents are loaded?

Comment: no it's not that. i just simplified it so u could know what it is

Comment: I'm only going to put this in the comments cause I don't really have a source for this. I'm pretty sure, however, that you cannot manipulate elements inside of an iframe. That's probably why you're having trouble.

Comment: what's your html? do you have anything with id="iframe"? the # inside the selector is for ID, guess that that's what's causing the wrong behavior..

Comment: If it's "simple as that" then it's not working because you're missing the HTML iframe you're trying to reference.

Comment: You'll probably want to define "doesn't work".

Comment: "doesn't work" means it doesn't do anything. LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access iframes you need to use 'contents':

```
  $('#iframe').ready(function() {
       $('#iframe').contents().find('a').attr('target', '_parent');
  });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, 'ready' doesn't work with iframes, so the content is probably not available when you call this.  You need to wait, or provide a callback in your iframe.  Or, use load as stated in another answer.  But, contents should work if the frame is loaded and on the same domain.

Comment: You're right! awesome. it worked with a timeout on a function.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using a .load() event instead?  See  the below question.

[Javascript callback when IFRAME is finished loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164085/javascript-callback-when-iframe-is-finished-loading)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because you could not modify the cross-domain `iframe` document in JavaScript.