# Jquery ('#iframeid').load() is executed before Iframe CONTENT (text, images) are loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, internet-explorer-8, jquery-load

I'm trying to access data of an Iframe's Iframe. To force my javascript function to wait I use jqueries .load function. But still my javascript code get's executed "sometimes" before the iframe's content is fully loaded. By sometimes I mean that the behavior is different for different computers. On slower computers it waits most times for fasters computers the code gets almost always executed. So I suspect that Internet explorer 8 fires the onload event to early. Is there any jquery function to wait until all elements of an iframe are loaded?

This is my code:

```
function parsePeopleLink(){
try{
    //This is where I check if the wanted I frame already exists
    if(document.getElementById('isolatedWorkArea') != null) {
        if(window.frames[2] != null) {
            if(window.frames[2].name == 'isolatedWorkArea') {
                //This is where I want the following code only to be executed when the Iframe's content is fully loaded, otherwise I get an access denied error when trying to change Userlinks
                $('#isolatedWorkArea').load(function() {
                    for( var i = 0; i < window.frames.length; i++){
                        for(var j = 0; j< window.frames[i].document.frames.length; j++){
                            IframeDocument = window.frames[i].document.frames[j].document;
                            changeUserLink(findPeopleIDfix(findPeopleID(IframeDocument)),findUserLinks(IframeDocument),8, IframeDocument);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                throw e; //I know that all the nested else statements are ugly, I just inserted them for testing purposes
            }   
        }
        else {
            throw e;
        }
    }
    else {
        throw e;
    }
}
catch(e) {
    //alert(e.description);
    for(var k = 0; k < window.frames.length; k++)
    {
        IframeDocument = window.frames[k].document;
        changeUserLink(findPeopleIDfix(findPeopleID(IframeDocument)),findUserLinks(IframeDocument),9, IframeDocument);      
        iframeindex++;
    }
  }
}
```

All Iframes have: same port, protocoll, and src.
Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript can't access external content to monitor when it's completely loaded. If you have access to the iframe content you can add a call to the parent window's function to trigger it.

Parent Page:

```
function parsePeopleLink() {
    //all your current code like you have it now
}
```

Framed Page:

```
$(function(){
    parent.parsePeopleLink();
    //This will monitor the document being ready in the framed page 
    //and then trigger the parent's function
});
```

Comment: I'm not trying to load external content. Sry for the misunderstanding. The content inside the Iframe is UserId Links and Images, I want to change those links to a custom link I designed. My Main Javascript script is called by the parent page with $(document).ready(function(){}); This function (a parser) should then change all the links in the iframe to my custom links. I do not really have access to modify content of the iframe as it is rendered by the Iframe..  Could you explain your solution a bit more detailed?

Comment: The parent page would need to access the iframe content to determine when it's loaded which is not possible. The framed page has to trigger a function in the parent page that lets it know that it's loaded. Then you could trigger your parsePeopleLink function. About to edit my code above to show you what I mean.

Comment: the LOAD event on the iframe fire when content STARTS loading, not when it is complete. You need to run $(document).ready() from within the Iframe and call a function in the parent window.

Comment: Sorry, but how can I append the html of the Iframe before it's ready? When I try to access the iframe (attribute of iframe) I get "Access denied Error"..

Comment: Right, which is where the problem is. The only way you can do it is if you have access to the iframed page's source to be able to add that script.

Comment: Oh ok. But thanks anyway for your help. I will keep googling and edit my post if I find something.

Answer (score 3):

I used something like that in one of my projects. I was trying to download a file, and show message after download finished. This kind of thing didn't work in my experience:

```
$('#myiframe').attr("src","http://example.com");
$('#myiframe').load(function() { /* do work on load */ });
```

Load event fires immediately after iframe is written in HTML not when iframe loads all of its contents. But this code worked:

```
$('#myiframe').load("http://example.com", function() { /* do work on load */ });
```

This code waited for my file to download then fired load event. I think this could work for you too.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to hide the waiting spinner div when the i frame content is fully loaded on IE, 
i tried literally every solution mentioned in Stackoverflow.Com, but with nothing worked as i wanted.

Then i had an idea, that when the i frame content is fully loaded, the $(Window ) load event might be fired. 
And that exactly what happened. 
So, i wrote this small script, and worked like magic:

```
$(window).load(function () {
         //alert("Done window ready ");
         var lblWait = document.getElementById("lblWait");
         if (lblWait != null ) {
             lblWait.style.visibility = "false";
             document.getElementById("divWait").style.display = "none";
         }
     });
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

How/where are you triggering the load of the iframe?  If you check these solutions a pattern of:

```
$('#myiframe').attr('src', 'http://example.com');
$('#myiframe').load(function() { /* do work on load */ });
```

is reported to work.

Similar reported solutions:

[jQuery .ready in a dynamically inserted iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205087/jquery-ready-in-a-dynamically-inserted-iframe)
[Javascript callback when IFRAME is finished loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164085/javascript-callback-when-iframe-is-finished-loading)

Edit:

Looks like Nick Spiers has the right answer, or at least it's part of your problem.  Access issues on the iframe contents.

Comment: Nope sry doesn't work. I still get Access denied error in Internet Explorer. And just btw: I thought I was using this function: [Jquery .load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

Comment: Right turns out there are two `load` methods, based on argument overloading.  I'll add an edit concerning this.

Comment: Do you mean to re-set the src of the Iframe? To be honest I'm actually not loading the Iframe myself. It is loaded by a framework. So I'm not sure how setting the src of the iframe again will help me?

Comment: Yes that's just the pattern from the other question which was marked as working.  It doesn't apply as well to your situation.

Comment: Oh I see now. I'm trying to attach the load event to the Iframe, but the problem I'm having now is that the iframe i need to change is the child of another iframe. So I can't use the iframe's id to access it.. Any suggestions?

Comment: Haha sorry man, not really.  Iframes inside iframes, this is getting a bit hairy for me :-)