# Event when iframe finishes loading

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript callback when IFRAME is finished loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164085/javascript-callback-when-iframe-is-finished-loading)

Is there an event I can watch for to see when an iFrame has finished loading? It will always be an external file being loaded in the iFrame (not on my domain) if that makes any difference.

Comment: This questions has been asked 300 times. Please consult one of the other questions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205087/jquery-ready-in-a-dynamically-inserted-iframe