# jquery wait until iframe is loaded

Tags: jquery, iframe, load

Hello, I'm using a button in order to change the src of an iframe when I click it this way:

```
$("#iframe").attr('src',"someurl");
```

Is there any way to display a "Please wait" message or a gif loader until the new URL is loaded?

Comment: is the content in `someurl` in your control?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript callback when IFRAME is finished loading?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164085/javascript-callback-when-iframe-is-finished-loading)

Comment: yes its a local php file

Answer (score 5):

Why not use jQuery.load function which has a callback for managing displayed text:

HTML

```
<button id="myLoadButton">Load</button>
<div id="Myiframe"></div>
```

JS

```
$('#myLoadButton').click(function(){
   $(this).text('Please wait...');
   $('#Myiframe').load('ajax/test.html', function(){
      $('#myLoadButton').text('Content loaded!');
   });
})
```

Comment: I was going to down vote but maybe I am missing something, so even if CROSS ORIGIN POLICY wasn't an issue and you would load google.com what about all the styles and scripts that would override your own?

Answer (score 1):

the src property just set the url for the frame but the load function is maintain by the jquery engine.so ajax global functions waits for load() function  to complete

```
 $("#iframe").attr('src',"someurl");
```

First make sure the ajax event be asynchronous 
and use this,

```
 $('#iframe').load('someurl');
```

this is the only way to display a "Please wait" message or a gif loader until the new URL is loaded