# jQuery unable to .find() elements in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have embeded jQuery mobile page using  in my HTML page, but when I try to access its internal div tag using jQuery, the find method returns nothing.

HTML With jQuery

```
<iframe id="myframe" src="../codiqa/mobile.htm" 
    style="width: 500px; height: 520px; 
    border: 1px solid #ccc; margin-top:20px;">
</iframe>
```

here

```
$("#myframe").load(function(){
    alert($(this).contents().find('#mobilebutton').html());     
});
```

mobile code in iframe

```
<div id="mobilebutton" data-role="button">Mobile Button</div>
```

Comment: Is the mobilebutton in the HTML of the IFrame, or in the main page?

Comment: I'm not sure, still try accessing the ID directly
    $("#myframe").load(function(){
        alert($('#mobilebutton').html());     
    });

Comment: <body class="design"> 
    <div id="_page" data-role="page">
    <div id="_header" data-role="header">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    
    <div id="_content" data-role="content">
    <div id="mobilebutton" data-role="button">Mobile Button</div>
    </div>
    
    <div id="_footer" data-role="footer">
    <h1>Footer</h1>
    </div>
    
    </div>
    
    
    
    </body>
</html>It is in the mobile page.

Comment: is `#mobilebutton` an immediate children of `#myframe`?

Comment: @Tom Sarduy

No, i have commented the code above .but there is no any other id in the whole page of that name

Comment: @Ark yes but it did'nt work

Comment: @user1175106: Update the question with the above code, so people don't have to read the comment thread ;)

Comment: Let me clear u all $(this).contents() return me an object but when i call .find() method on that object it does nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Works fine on IE.

Try it

```
alert($(this).contents().find('#mobilebutton').html());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.load` instead of `$("#myframe").load`. The elements of frame will be ready on $(window).load event and you will be able to access them.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    alert($("#myframe").contents().find('#mobilebutton').html());     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

According to jquery API guide: .html()
"Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements"

this way you need to add .parent in front of it to get the directed element. in this case:

```
$("#myframe").load(function(){
alert($(this).contents().find('#mobilebutton').parent.html()); });
```

In case you want to get the html of the button

Answer (score 0):

If @Adil solution doesn't work, you can try to add dynamically the iframe to attach the load event using this function:

```
function callIframe(url, callback) {
    $(document.body).append('<iframe id="myframe" 
                             style="width: 500px; height: 520px; 
                             border: 1px solid #ccc; margin-top:20px;">
                            </iframe> ');
    $('myframe').attr('src', url);
    $('myframe').load(function() 
    {
        alert($(this).contents().find('#mobilebutton').html())
    });
}
```

#### How to use it?

```
$('document').load(callIframe('../codiqa/mobile.htm'));
```

#### Further:

- [Iframes, onload, and document.domain](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/09/15/iframes-onload-and-documentdomain/)
- [Javascript callback when IFRAME is finished loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164085/javascript-callback-when-iframe-is-finished-loading)