# Applying a title tag to a frame within an iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to add title tags to frames within an iframe. All files reside on the same domain.

The full selector for the html page I am loading within the iframe is "html > frameset:nth-child(2) > frame:nth-child(1)"

However using even the following code does not update the attribute for any frames within the iframe.

```
$('#project_frame').contents().find('frame').attr('title','Table of Contents');

<iframe id="project_frame" name="project_frame" src="<?= $uri ?>" frameborder="0" title="project_frame"></iframe>
```

Comment: Try `$('#project_frame')[0].contents()...`.

Comment: That did not correct the issue.

Comment: What does the frame HTML inside the iframe look like?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't the attr() function simply add a title attribute to the iframe tag itself. I'm not sure if it's possible to directly manipulate HTML inside an iframe, and even if it is, it's definitely not good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iframe loading the source is asynchronous to the main execution, so here's a nice trick to make the desired code wait 'til it's loaded:

```
<iframe id="project_frame" name="project_frame" src="<?= $uri ?>" frameborder="0" title="project_frame"></iframe>

$("#project_frame").load(function () {
    $("#project_frame").contents().find('frame:first').attr('title', 'Table of Contents');
});
```

Found here: [Javascript callback when IFRAME is finished loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164085/javascript-callback-when-iframe-is-finished-loading)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("project_frame").contentWindow.document.title="MY TITLE";
```

Comment: From here, how does one access frame elements in the contents of the iframe? Also, there's a typo "getElememtById".

Comment: Hi. This code may well solve the problem.. but it'd be really nice if you could add a bit of explanation of what exactly you changed from the original and why the difference solves the issue. Don't forget that total newbies are on Stack Overflow all the time - and what may be a really obvious change to you (and why) would not be obvious to them. It's nice to help newbies learn something :)