# Javascript wait until iframe has reloaded

Tags: javascript, iframe, extjs4

Fixing the following javascript code contains my newest task:

```
// submit the form in the iframe:
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow.dojo.byId(buttonId).click(); 
// wait 50msec for result to be loaded:
window.setTimeout(function(){
    // get documentId of newly created document from result
    var docId = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].
                    contentWindow.dojo.byId("documentIdDiv").innerHtml;
    // put documentId into the outer form
    Ext.getCmp("form").getForm().findField("documentId").setValue(docId);
    // submit outer form
    Ext.getCmp("form").getForm().submit({
        ...
    });
}, 50);
// TODO: Error if result is not available after 50ms.
```

I now have to find a way to execute the anonymous function once the iframe has reloaded.

I thought of using a body onload on the iframe, but I can't, because I would have to insert it in the body of the new page.

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://github.com/wingify/please.js if you have complex interactions with iframes

Comment: Use this [IFrame Callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164085/javascript-callback-when-iframe-is-finished-loading)

Comment: @Neoaptt As far as I see, the solution would require jQuery, which I don't have. Could you make an answer elaborating on that, and include a JavaScript-only version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haha, trying to get this to work on JSFiddle was more difficult. Since they load javascript seperately from html. Anyways this should work.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/neoaptt/97a1gLsb/2/)

```
//function that happens when loaded
function loaded() {
    b.innerHTML = 'Call Back Worked';
};
//gets elements and sets them to variables
var b = document.getElementById('callback')
var a = document.getElementById("myframe");
//listens to load event
a.addEventListener("load", loaded());
```

Comment: Sorry, but this can't be working because even if you don't load the iFrame, "Callback worked" is written. Because loaded() is executed and the result is put into the event listener.

Comment: But I will try with addEventListener for myself. The problem of JSfiddle is that XSS is blocked in most browsers.

Comment: I got it working using `iframe.addEventListener("load",function() { iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementById(...)... });`