# How to display specific content after it has been loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I now I am not supposed to use links here as it will change but at the moment my problem can be seen at
http://8anime.net78.net/

The red under header thing has social buttons which load strangely. I want to hide them all, and when they are loaded display them.

Basically display 4 certain iframes after the content of the iframes have loaded.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164085/javascript-callback-when-iframe-is-finished-loading

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery 'load' function.

First hide the area. Then do the following action.

```
$('hiddenarea').on('load', function(){
    $(this).show();
});
```

For more details you can visit the following link

https://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Answer (score 0):

First make a div around the social items then hide the div with some css.

```
display: none
```

then add some jquery like this

```
jQuery(document).ready( function(){
    jQuery('#thehiddendivhere').fadeIn(1000);
} );
```