# When removing alert, the variable becomes undefined

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I have three separate tab panels with each being a table in my database. What i'm trying to do is that on a click of a button is save the content of all the three tabs in the database at the same time. I managed to do so by activating the tabs, then passing it certain value. However when i remove both alert functions from my code, i'm getting that B.RECORD is `undefined`. Any help on this?

```
      tabPanel.setActiveTab(1);
      tabPanel.setActiveTab(2);
      tabPanel.setActiveTab(0);

var B= window.frames["frm_B"];
var C= window.frames["frm_C"];

alert(B);
alert(C);
try {
    B.RECORD.getField("AID").setRealValue(aid);
    C.RECORD.getField("AID").setRealValue(aid);
    B.RECORD.update();
    C.RECORD.update();
    parent.refreshGrid();
    parent.win.close();
```

Comment: can you please copy paste your HTML code also!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the `alert()` gives you some time to load the `iframes`. You need to either use:

1. `setTimeout` giving an arbitrary load time for the frames.
2. Use `.load()` event of the frames.

I would prefer you use the `.load()` event, because it is dependable. So for that, put the following code and beyond inside the `load` event of the iframe:

```
try {
    B.RECORD.getField("AID").setRealValue(aid);
    C.RECORD.getField("AID").setRealValue(aid);
    B.RECORD.update();
    C.RECORD.update();
    parent.refreshGrid();
    parent.win.close();
```

The `load` event can be done using: [Javascript callback when IFRAME is finished loading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164085/javascript-callback-when-iframe-is-finished-loading)