# Add onload to iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a page with an iFrame on it.

I would like to add the following to the iFrame, with javascript, preferably no jQuery:

```
onload="resizeIframe(this)"
```

I do not have to target a specific class, I need the onload to be attached to all iFrames on the page.

Thanks!

EDIT

Right now my iframe looks like this:

```
<iframe width="100px" height="100px" src="#source">
```

I need it to look like this after page load:

```
<iframe width="100px" height="100px" src="#source" onload="resizeIframe(this)">
```

Hope that is a bit clearer, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript callback when IFRAME is finished loading?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164085/javascript-callback-when-iframe-is-finished-loading)

Answer (score 0):

```
var iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe'), i;

function MyFunction(){
console.log("iframe is loaded");
}

for (i = 0; i < iframes.length; ++i) {
  iframes[i].onload = MyFunction;
}
```