# Vimeo iframe: Show custom loading animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, plugins, vimeo

I'm using the Vimeo Plugin on my website like this:

```
<iframe class="vimeo" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/12345678" width="500" height="300" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Depending on my internet connection, Vimeo takes quite a while to load the videoplayer in the iframe. I'm not talking about loading the whole video but to load the player into the iframe. Now I was wondering if I could show a custom loading animation like a turning clock while the player is loading in the background. As soon as the Vimeo plugin is completely loaded it should be shown to the user.

A jQuery, HTML, CSS solution would be great.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164085/javascript-callback-when-iframe-is-finished-loading)

Comment: Thanks but sorry I have no idea how to apply it to my problem. Can you help me out with some hints where to put the code and how to use this function? Any help will be higly appreciated.