# Iframe onload event fires before document is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have the following JavaScript code

```
frame.onload = function()
{
  // Get element
}
frame.src = url //url is an external and I don't have control over it
```

But here frame.onload event fires before the frame fully loaded. If I set timeout for 5 seconds after that I can get needed element.
So how to wait frame to fully load?

Comment: Use callbacks, like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/209723/640263

Comment: @toggy-tog-togs how?

Comment: @toggy-tog-togs He is using a callback.

Comment: @Barmar You are right, sorry. I created this small fiddle, and I can access the elements within perfectly fine (on load), https://jsfiddle.net/e6hgfrk6/. Could you possibly provide more of your code/detail so we can see what is going on?

Comment: What kinds of elements are you having trouble accessing? Are they being loaded by Javascript? The `onload` event doesn't wait for Javascript to run, so it can't wait for those elements to load.

Comment: Yes there could be elements that are being loaded by JavaScript. But I read about onload it says that it fires once a web page has completely loaded all content (including images, script files, CSS files, etc.).

Comment: @AshotKhachatryan Any luck with a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use the `load` event of the document contained in the iframe, not the iframe itself.

```
frame.onload = function() {
    frame.contentDocument.onload = function () {
        // Get element
    };
};
frame.src = url;
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar but this event doesn't fire at all.

Comment: Try my updated answer, where it doesn't set the content document's load event until after the iframe is initially loaded.

Comment: Is the iframe in the same domain as the main document? You can't access iframe contents across domains.

Comment: Yes they are in the same domain when I add timeout inside frame.onload I successfully get what I need. In the updated example contentDocument.onload doesn't fire as well.